# getSelection() and insertNode -- Javascript Text Selection

Tags: javascript, text, range, selection, getselection

Does anyone know how to set the browser selection to a newly / independently created range? I understand how to get the text selection from the browser, and I understand how to create a range, but I don't know how to tell the browser to change the selection to the range I've created. I would have thought it would be something like "setSelection".

To be clear, I'm not trying to cause the selection of a textarea - I'm talking about p / div / ul tags etc.

I was referencing the following site (maybe it'll give you an idea?):

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a range that is a DOM `Range` in non-IE browsers and a `TextRange` in IE:

```
function selectRange(range) {
    var sel;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        // Non-IE browsers
        sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.selection && range.select) {
        // IE
        range.select();
    }
}
```